# How to add imap module after PHP have configured and make & make install?

Tags: php, imap

There is a method to add imap for php:

```
cd /root/lnmp1.3-full/src/php-7.0.8/ext/imap
/usr/local/php/bin/phpize
./configure -with-imap -with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config --with-kerberos=/usr --with-imap-ssl=/usr
make
make install
```

but the PHP I have make and installed.

so, if I have configured and installed PHP, now I want to add the `imap` for PHP, how can I do that? can I still use the upper method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before.

Brief steps:

1. get the same source code of the php you have installed
2. `./configure -with-imap ...` and `make`
3. find the `imap.so` in the build output
4. copy the `imap.so` to your installed php's extension dir
5. change the installed php's `php.ini` and load the `imap.so`
6. verify with `php -i`

If you are familar with php's building system, you may `cd ext/imap` and use `phpize / configure / make` to build the imap module only.

Comment: do you mean, re-configure and re-make it? do not re-install php?

Comment: If you can re-install, it also works (of coz).  If you do not want to re-install, you can just "build" a new php (the same version) with the imap module, and copy the imap module to your existing php.